# Python Iterate list sequentialy to pair with every next value

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, python-itertools

Having the following list `[13, 7, 0, 0, 0, 356, 356]`

I need to iterate to get pairs like `(13, 7), (7, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 356), (356, 356)`

I have been thinkering around itertools methods but so far itertools.permutations() is the closest to what im looking for a but excessive and so not the exact solution.

Comment: What did you try, why was it not the exact solution?

Comment: This is a duplicated for sure. I remember answering this question already. But it is my bedtime already....